# How to debug RoutedCommands

Tags: wpf

I have a Control that holds a TabControl, bound to an ObservableCollection and a RoutedUICommand to add a TabItem. There is one initial Tab added to the TabControl. The CommandBindings.Add() for the RoutedCommand is set on the Control. Everything works fine until the very first TabItem is deleted by the user. From thereon the RoutedCommand is no longer received by the handler.

My question is: How can I debug here or find out what is going on?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Have you tried [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)? It lets you inspect WPF windows and see all properties, DataContexts and a lot of other stuff.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the behavior in a small program to post but then the effect did not show up. Therefore I am looking for a way to debug.